# Guess the number game Python

Tags: python

So, im new to python and i have this challenge: I have to make the Guess the Number game, between me and computer. So this is where im at so far.

```
import random


the_number = random.randint(1, 4)
guess = 0

print(the_number)
while guess != the_number:
    guess = int(input("Please enter a number: "))
    if guess > the_number:
        print("Player guess lower...\n")
    elif guess < the_number:
        print("Player guess higher...\n")
    else:
        print("Game Over! The number was", the_number,"The Player wins!")
        break


    guess = random.randint(1, 100)

    if guess > the_number:
        print("Computer guess lower...\n")
    elif guess < the_number:
        print("Computer guess higher...\n")
    else:
        print("Game Over! The number was", the_number,"The Computer wins!")
    break


print("Thank you for playing")
```

I wanna know how to make this to not stop until one of us is right?

Comment: Tab your break statement for the computer's part. Regardless of its guess, the code breaks at the end of the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this to make the computer smarter.

```
import random

the_number = random.randint(1, 4)
guess = 0

print(the_number)
minPossible = 0
maxPossible = 100

while guess != the_number:
    guess = int(input("Please enter a number: "))
    if guess > the_number:
        print("Player, guess lower...\n")
        if guess < maxPossible:
            maxPossible = guess - 1
    elif guess < the_number:
        print("Player, guess higher...\n")
        if guess > minPossible:
            minPossible = guess + 1
    else:
        print("Game Over! The number was", the_number, "The Player wins!")
        break

    guess = random.randint(minPossible, maxPossible)

    if guess > the_number:
        print("Computer, guess lower...\n")
        maxPossible = guess - 1
    elif guess < the_number:
        print("Computer, guess higher...\n")
        minPossible = guess + 1
    else:
        print("Game Over! The number was", the_number,"The Computer wins!")


print("Thank you for playing")
```

Comment: The break isn't really necessary, the guess equals the_number, so the loop will end on its own.

Comment: True. Edited answer.

Comment: Thank you. btw is there a way i can make computer's guesses "smarter" after each round? Like if I guess 10, and its lower, so Computer recognizes that and guesses lower than that.

Comment: @zenalc thank you. but I need to figure it out to make it smarter lol.

Comment: Well, the computer logic is put in the code above is pretty basic, but basically, if you guess something too low, the minimum for the computer to guess would be that guess + 1, and if your guess was too high, the maximum for the computer to guess would be that guess - 1. Keep going through with that logic until someone wins.

Comment: well, lets say I guess first number 50, and its a lower number, so now on computer side it will guess smth from 1 to 49. And then when its my turn again if i guess number 1, the computer will guess anything from 2 to 100. does that make sense?

Comment: The computer does that in the code above. That's how minPossible and maxPossible help the computer decide what value to pick.

Comment: Let me try to explain again. Lets say the guess number is 25. My turn i say first 50. Computer goes lower than that, lets say 30. On my turn again I go lets say 10, the computer i gonna go higher maybe 80. So theres no point for the computer to go over smth that earlier was called for 50 or 30

Answer (score 2):

```
# Import random library
import random
# Assign random value between 1-100
secret_number = random.randint(1, 100)
# get the user guess
guess = int(input("Guess the secret number between 1-100: "))

# Loop untill guess not equal to secret number
while guess != secret_number:
    if guess < secret_number:
        print("Sorry, your guess is too low.")
    else:
        print("Sorry, your guess is too high.")
    
    # guess the number again
    guess = int(input("Guess the secret number between 1-100: "))
 
# This statement will execute after coming out of while loop
print("You guessed the number!")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the `break` statement at the end of the while loop. The code is iterating through the loop one time, then the `break` is ending the loop.

Answer (score 0):

To get the desired output, you just need to tweak the code a bit, the `break` in the if statement for the computer is out of the loop of else, so it will stop the execution no matter what.

To counter this condition, you can move the `break` inside the `else` block. By doing this, the program will only break if either CPU or you correctly guess the right number.

One more thing i wanted to point out is you are printing the selecting number in the program, if it is a guessing game, isn't it supposed to be in the back-end of the code. By entering the printed number, you can win the game in the first iteration.

And just to point out, your program is selecting the number from `(1, 4)` but the computer is set to guess the number from `(1, 100)`.
Kindly tick the answer if it is correct.
The modified code is -

```
import random


the_number = random.randint(1, 4)
guess = 0

while guess != the_number:
    guess = int(input("Please enter a number: "))
    if guess > the_number:
        print("Player guess lower...\n")
    elif guess < the_number:
        print("Player guess higher...\n")
    else:
        print("Game Over! The number was", the_number,"The Player wins!")
        break

    guess = random.randint(1, 4)

    if guess > the_number:
        print("Computer guess lower...\n")
    elif guess < the_number:
        print("Computer guess higher...\n")
    else:
        print("Game Over! The number was", the_number,"The Computer wins!")
        break


print("Thank you for playing")
```